# How to stop mutiple activity indicator animation in multiple webview?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

Currently i am developing a sample where i am displaying 4 webview in ipad screen and trying to show 4 different URL in them.

All the web pages are showing in the webview perfectly.

Also i am displaying 4 activity indicator once the webpage starts loading.

But i can not figure out how to stop activity indicator in all the respective webpage one by one once they are loaded in to the screen.

```
-(void)createWebView
{

    //******************** First *********

    firstWebView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
    firstWebView.frame=CGRectMake(10, 50, 350, 470);
    firstWebView.delegate=self;
    firstIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
                                        initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    firstIndicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
    firstIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.firstWebView addSubview:firstIndicator];
    [firstIndicator startAnimating];
    firstWebView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
     NSURL *firstUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.techtree.com"];
     NSURLRequest *firstRequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:firstUrl];
    [firstWebView loadRequest:firstRequestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:firstWebView]; 

    //******************* Second *********

    secondWebView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
    secondWebView.frame=CGRectMake(405, 50, 350, 470);
    secondWebView.delegate=self;

    secondIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
                      initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    secondIndicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
    secondIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.secondWebView addSubview:secondIndicator];
    [secondIndicator startAnimating];
    secondWebView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    NSURL *secondUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"];
    NSURLRequest *secondRequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:secondUrl];
    [secondWebView loadRequest:secondRequestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:secondWebView]; 


    //****************** Third ************

    thirdWebView=[[UIWebView alloc] init];
    thirdWebView.frame=CGRectMake(10, 528, 350, 470);
    thirdWebView.delegate=self;


    thirdIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
                       initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    thirdIndicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
    thirdIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.thirdWebView addSubview:thirdIndicator];
    [thirdIndicator startAnimating];

    thirdWebView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    NSURL *thirdUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"];
    NSURLRequest *thirdRequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:thirdUrl];
    [thirdWebView loadRequest:thirdRequestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:thirdWebView];

    //***************** Fourth ************
    fourthWebView=[[UIWebView alloc] init];
    fourthWebView.frame=CGRectMake(405,528, 350, 470);
    fourthWebView.delegate=self;


    fourthIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
                      initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    fourthIndicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
    fourthIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.fourthWebView addSubview:fourthIndicator];
    [fourthIndicator startAnimating];

    fourthWebView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    NSURL *fourthUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"];
    NSURLRequest *fourthRequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fourthUrl];
    [fourthWebView loadRequest:fourthRequestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:fourthWebView];


    //******************** Memory Managemt **********
    [firstWebView release];
    [secondWebView release];
    [thirdWebView release];
    [fourthWebView release];

    [firstIndicator release];
    [secondIndicator release];
    [thirdIndicator release];
    [fourthIndicator release];


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
overwrite below delegate method and check which webview is loading finished like below

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   if(webView== firstWebView)
   { 
     [firstIndicator setHidden:YES];
   }
  else
  {
     so on...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Its working.One more question how can i make it more faster as it is taking too much time to load all the web page.